# Copy value of variable in Excel 2016 macro to new doc in Word 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert in a W10 Excel 2016 macro some code that will

open a new Word 2016 document and
copy the value of variable "s" (string) from the Excel macro to that new Word document
then returns to the Excel macro.

Maybe it helps that I know Word can be opened with this macro:

```
Sub startWord()

Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftWord

End Sub
```

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a simple copy of a string into a new Word document, then the following code should work.  You haven’t indicated where you get the string from, so I’ve used the contents of cell A1 on Sheet1.  You can adjust this to suit.

*For the following to work, you need to enable a reference within VBA. In the VBA Editor, select Tools/References & check the box ‘Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library’. If it’s not already checked, you’ll find it listed alphabetically.*

This works for me – let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WordApp As Word.Application, myDoc As Word.Document, s As String
Sub CopyToWord()

On Error Resume Next
    
Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
On Error GoTo 0

If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

    s = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    
    With myDoc.Content
        .Text = s
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @chris neilsen Thanks Chris, good point and code edited. Cheers!